# Aspose.Words spanning pages with a table C# MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, words, aspose

I have an MVC3 C#.Net web app.  We are using Aspose.Words to export our data into a word document.  One of the items being created in the document is a labor summary table.  This table starts in the middle of the page (in other words, it's not the first element on the page so it's starting point will vary depending on data).  Often times the table spans onto the next page, again depending how much data is above the table and how many rows are in the table.  We have a requirement from the customer that, if the table spans pages, we need to start the new page with a row of headers, then the rest of the data rows.

This requires me to know:

1. how much room I have left on the first page for the table:  how much space is left from the point where the table will be inserted to the end of the page
2. how tall the table will be when filled

I don't know how to get either of those two pieces of data.  Can someone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have again gone through your requirement **We have a requirement from the customer that, if the table spans pages, we need to start the new page with a row of headers, then the rest of the data rows.** As per my understanding, you need to have header row repeated on all pages where table is placed.

Please note that Microsoft Word documents have a built-in feature for adding header rows to tables so they are repeated on each page that the table appears on. There is no need to detect where a table starts and ends. Please see [Specifying Rows to Repeat on Subsequent Pages as Header Rows](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Specifying+Rows+to+Repeat+on+Subsequent+Pages+as+Header+Rows) in Aspose.Words for .NET documentation for further details.